# Matplotlib обрезает подписи

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Обрезается ось Z. На аналогичные вопросы советуют использовать `plt.tight_layout()`, но в моем случае почему-то не работает

```
data = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hse-ds/iad-intro-ds/master/2022/homeworks/hw03-EDA/german_credit.csv")
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (17, 8), dpi=72, subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})
ax.set_ylabel("Duration")
ax.set_xlabel("Credit amount")
ax.set_zlabel("Age")
ax.scatter(data=good, xs="amount", ys="duration", zs = "age", c="g")
ax.scatter(data=bad, xs="amount", ys="duration", zs="age", c="r")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй вместо `plt.tight_layout()` добавить:

```
ax.dist = 12
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня все равно не работает

Answer (score 1):

В дополнение привожу экземпляр полностью рабочего кода:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hse-ds/iad-intro-ds/master/2022/homeworks/hw03-EDA/german_credit.csv")
good = data[data['credit_risk'] == 'good']
bad = data[data['credit_risk'] == 'bad']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(17, 8), dpi=72,
                       subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})
ax.set_ylabel("Duration")
ax.set_xlabel("Credit amount")
ax.set_zlabel("Age")
ax.scatter(data=good, xs="amount", ys="duration", zs="age", c="g")
ax.scatter(data=bad, xs="amount", ys="duration", zs="age", c="r")
ax.dist = 12
plt.show()
```